How is communion interpreted in context with Leviticus 3:17, Leviticus 17:11, John 6:53-56, and Matthew 26:27-29?
I have recently come upon a subject that I'd not encountered before. A friend has questioned the passages involving drinking "blood" in communion, believing it to have been added by the Roman Catholic Church of that day.
In Leviticus, we read the following:

It shall be a statute forever throughout your generations, in all your
dwelling places, that you eat neither fat nor blood. - Leviticus 3:17
ESV


For the life of the flesh is in the blood, and I have given it for you
on the altar to make atonement for your souls, for it is the blood
that makes atonement by the life. - Leviticus 17:11 ESV

This also calls into question the following passages in the New Testament:

So Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, unless you eat the
flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you have no life in you.
Whoever feeds on my flesh and drinks my blood has eternal life, and I
will raise him up on the last day. For my flesh is true food, and my
blood is true drink. Whoever feeds on my flesh and drinks my blood
abides in me, and I in him. As the living Father sent me, and I live
because of the Father, so whoever feeds on me, he also will live
because of me. - John 6:53-57 ESV


And he took a cup, and when he had given thanks he gave it to them,
saying, “Drink of it, all of you, for this is my blood of the
covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. I
tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until that
day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.” - Matthew
26:27-29 ESV


In the same way also he took the cup, after supper, saying, “This cup
is the new covenant in my blood. Do this, as often as you drink it, in
remembrance of me.” For as often as you eat this bread and drink the
cup, you proclaim the Lord's death until he comes.- I Corinthians
11:25,26 ESV

He has no issue with the body or the bread as it is reflected in the Old Testament, but the drink of "blood" he finds no witness. To the contrary, there is a prohibition against drinking blood. He says we shouldn't even be imagining it.
Are we drinking blood?

You could improve the question by including explicit quotations of the cited scriptures (so everyone doesn't have to look them up).

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Jevon! When you get a chance, please take the  tour to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. Also consider going through the Help Center's  sections on asking and answering questions.

Some questions, does he have evidence that these were added by the RCC? Does he take issue with the Catholic doctrine of transubstantiation or does he object even to the belief that it's a symbolic act not actually drinking blood?

"*the RCC of that day".  It would help if the question explicitly expanded "RCC" and indicated when "that day" refers to. Don't make people have to guess what you mean.

Hi Jevon, Because you're new to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum, I edited your question to the style guidelines here as an example for you. This includes a specific title, quoted the actual verses, and expanded abbreviations, This makes your question easier to answer.

I think the very end of this question is not a hermeneutical question, and would be best answered on https://christianity.stackexchange.com

Paul F. Bradshaw and John Dominic Crossan are two scholars who have written that the eucharistic tradition of the gospels may not have be instituted by Jesus at the Last Supper. They follow a tradition instituted by Rudolph Bultmann suggesting that many doctrines and practices of the early church were influenced by pagan practices and myths.
However, it is hard to argue that the cup (drinking Jesus' blood) is a later addition to the text of the gospels. Nevertheless there is clear evidence that the idea was hard for the Jews of Jesus' day to accept:
John 6

52 The Jews quarreled among themselves, saying, “How can this man give
us [his] flesh to eat?” 53 Jesus said to them, “Amen, amen, I say to
you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood,
you do not have life within you.... When many of his disciples heard
it, they said, This is a hard saying; who can listen to it? 61. But
Jesus, knowing in himself that his disciples were grumbling about
this, said to them, Do you take offense at this? 62. Then what if you
were to see the Son of Man ascending to where he was before? 63. It is
the Spirit who gives life; the flesh is of no avail. The words that I
have spoken to you are spirit and life.

Of course, scholars are practically unanimous is holding the John's was the last Gospel to be written, and that the eucharistic tradition is one of its central themes. But the tradition of the cup goes back to Paul who says:
1 Cor 11

I received from the Lord what I also handed on to you, that the Lord
Jesus, on the night he was handed over, took bread, 24 and, after he
had given thanks, broke it and said, “This is my body that is for you.
Do this in remembrance of me.” 25 In the same way also the cup, after
supper, saying, “This cup is the new covenant in my blood. Do this, as
often as you drink it, in remembrance of me.”

There are questions as to whether Paul "received" this tradition from the church or from a personal revelation - literally "from the Lord." But in either case, there is no evidence that the idea of drinking Jesus' blood was a later addition to the text. Rather, it is part of a tradition that existed in the church from no later than the writing of 1 Corinthians.
Conclusion: Scholars have long questioned whether the historical Jesus truly instituted the tradition of the cup (blood-drinking) at the Last Supper. However, none that I know of argue that this is a later addition to the text. That this tradition was hard even from some believers to accept is clearly evident in the text of John.
